# Select Image From Gallery And Display It On ImageView, Issue On Nexus 5

Tags: android, imageview, onactivityresult

I have a very weird issue, I want the user to select an image and display it on a ImageView, the code works perfectly on my Xiaomi mi52 (V4.1.1) and my Xiaomi MiPad (V4.4.4) but it's totally failed on my Nexus 5 (V5.0).

```
public class CreateContactActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imgProfile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_contact);
        imgProfile = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgProfileIV);
    }

    public void ImageProfile(View view) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case 100:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    imgProfile.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                }
           }
    }
}
```

Layout activity_create_contact.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProfileIV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_person"
        android:onClick="ImageProfile" />


</LinearLayout>
```

On LogCat I get these errors:

```
12-10 15:33:18.348 D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
12-10 15:33:18.350 I/System.out﹕ resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://media/external/images/media/72
```

The weird this is it's just on my Nexus 5, not on the Xiaomi devices. I'm looking and looking but I don't understand where is the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Works just fine on my Nexus 5

Comment: thanks for your help, very weird, any idea when it can come from?

Comment: Does it do it on any image you select? and what app are you using to select image.

Comment: it display nothing, it remove the default image. I'm using the system app to select image (I guess).

Comment: I meant do you get that error for every image

Comment: No in fact I get the error just this one image, taken with the camera. I took over with the camera and no error, just for one.

Comment: Hello, I used this code to run on Xiomi 4A using Eclipse. However, when I have written same code in Androis Studio, then the image is not visible. Could anyone tell me the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in result may come from the "picker" you chose on different platform.

You should try to do control experiment by installing same file explorer app as picker so that we can make sure the problem comes from difference in Android version