# ImageView is not showing image in Xiomi Smartphone

Tags: android

I have written a program to browse image gallery and show the selected image in the ImageView using AndroidStudio. I have got a sample code from [Select Image From Gallery And Display It On ImageView, Issue On Nexus 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403703/select-image-from-gallery-and-display-it-on-imageview-issue-on-nexus-5.)

It is working well in stock android running Smartphone like LG L70 set. But no image is visible on the imageview for Xiomi 4A.

For experimentation, I have written the same code in Eclipse editor. The code developed by Eclipse running well both LG L70 and Xiomi 4A.

Hence, it is clear that code is not problem. The problem must be from IDE. Could you please help me to solve this problem. Where should I modify the code, so that it will run on Xiomi developed by AndroidStudio.

[Codes in gdrive.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oa5zQaU3tKNEar1l1bB8oT1-VJHLHUlV?usp=sharing)

Code

```
package com.example.nasif.xiomi_imageview2;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ImageView imgProfile;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgProfile = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgProfileIV);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Perform action on click
                //new MyAsyncTask(this).execute("ppppp");
                Log.d("MyTag", "1");
                ImageProfile();
            }
        });
    }

    public void ImageProfile()
    {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case 100:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    imgProfile.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                    Log.d("MyTag", "@: " + selectedImage);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "@: " + selectedImage, LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nasif.xiomi_imageview2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nasif.xiomi_imageview2.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProfileIV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/a"
        android:onClick="ImageProfile" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgProfileIV"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Debug you code an make sure that you're getting a valid image Uri back.

Comment: I have debugged. Logging returns a valid Uri.                                                                     
 12-01 21:44:04.418 3344-3344/com.example.nasif.xiomi_imageview2 D/MyTag: @: file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/aaa.jpg

Comment: Try this code "imgProfile.setImageBitmap(selectedImage.toString()));"

Comment: It gives a compile error. Please see the image capture of the error. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=115bDADs-oZrD3BmWNwBZlsxpv164HG20)

Comment: Sorry, the code should be this:  
"imgProfile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decode(selectedImage.toString()));"

Comment: I have modified the code. imgProfile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImage.toString())); However, no image is visible in  the ImageView.

Comment: Try checking the width of the ImageView. Maybe it's to small or or the images is to large and the imageView is failing because you've set the width and height to wrap content but it's content is greater than the space available. I've never experienced this problem and I cannot find any resources that mention similar issues. You can check the size of the actual image by calling getWidth and getHeight on the bitmap returned from BitmapFactory.decode().

Comment: I have tried with image 150 * 100 pixel. But it is not working. It is very odd. The same code is working for Xiomi if I used Eclipse IDE instead of AndroidStudio. Thank you for your suggestions.